# Как убрать отступ справа при уменьшении экрана

Tags: отступы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать нежелательный отступ справа при уменьшении экрана (в chrome инспектирование мобильные устройства) Ссылка: https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/metro-ui-corporate-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/